# Slow AIR startup when too many files are in directory where application was installed

Tags: apache-flex, file, air, adobe, startup

I'm writing an application that uses over a couple of thousand files and I have the following problem. When application is starting up it takes a couple of minutes to get to the first screen. I've narrowed the problem to be associated with the number of files in the application installation directory. After removing these files application starts up normally. The weird thing is that the debug version of the app starts normally. The problem only exists in the release version after its installation. 
I have to add that I load like 30 xml files on startup which should not be so uncommon but trying to get to the bottom of this I've even turned this off. The thousands of files I'm speaking of are untouched during the startup process they just reside in the installation directory. Once I move them out of the directory application starts up within a second.
Does anyone know what AIR might be doing in that time? I've observed some CPU activity of the app like 10-20% and application seems to allocate memory for some unknown reason during the waiting.
Is AIR checking all the files on startup? Is there a way to turn this checkup process off?

Comment: First, why are you using so many files? Second, why do you have 30 xml files?  I've worked on some of the world's largest Flex projects and never had to use 30 different xml files...Also, which version of Air are you using? What's the OS? etc etc...

Comment: OS is Win7, Air 2.6. Application is a house project configurator (you choose a roof, wall, number of windows etc.) and each xml is a house config. I can't actually implement lazy loading of these easily beacause I need to know many things about the houses at startup. Thousands of files are how I got the visuals, they're just images of houses cut into small pieces. Anyway that's not the problem, just application specific thing. The problem is that application loads ridiculously long with that many files in installation directory. Any idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of this before, but after looking online, I did [find this](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2008/06/dont_write_to_app_dir.html).  It might be a problem with your OS' restricting you access.  Either way, you might want to look into the user's local storage instead of the applications.

Comment: Can I install these files into local storage somehow? So far I moved the files into documents which fixes the loading time issue but is not a good option because these files won't get removed after uninstallation for one and the installation process is 2 step with 2 packages. Is there a way to not install the files into app directory but somewhere else instead?

Comment: Well, you're probably using an install wizard right? You can save those files under the "user directory/application data/your app".  I'm not sure about the normal Air install however...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. I havn't been using native installer, just AIR one. Greatly appreciated. I've found this article to help me out through custom installation process of AIR app:
[link](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/08/adobe-air-distribution-and-installation/). Maybe this is gonna help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Files distributed with AIR application are digitally signed. If signatures are verified on each startup, this may explain why it happens only in release.
Thousands of files may be worth of packing in zip archive. It's easy to extract them with any smart zip-library and single zip file will decrease install/uninstall time.